# android thread on repeated call method

Tags: android, multithreading, geolocation

I have a thread called `checkUpdate` inside this method:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    checkUpdate = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
          try {
               // do some long staff using location variable            
              } catch (Exception e) {}
          handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
     };
    checkUpdate.start();
```

The problem is that the `onLocationChanged()` method is called by the system, sometimes before the thread has finished and this causes unpredictable behaviour in my application.

Is there any way to not run the thread if is already running or something similar?

---

SOLUTION:

I know what's going on, you need to call `locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);`
and set `locationManager=null` on your destroy activity, otherwise even if the app is closed, the service is still running and fetching locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way not to run the thread if is already running or something similar

You could use an `AtomicBoolean` to set a value which tells you whether or not to start the thread.  Then at the end of the `run()` method, you could reset the flag to be false.

Something like the following should work:

```
private final AtomicBoolean threadStarted = new AtomicBoolean(false);
...
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (threadStarted.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        // start the thread
        checkUpdate = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // do thread stuff here
                } finally {
                    // when the thread finishes, set the started flag to false
                    threadStarted.set(false);
                }
            }
        };
        checkUpdate.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code @Xenione.  Can you put some logging in to see if the thread is being started?

Comment: ok. may be is something wrong with the handler, probably becouse I have to set threadStarted to True when the handler task is done.do you know how to do that?. thanks

Comment: When it is done @Xenione, you set the started flag to _false_.  My sample code above shows how to do that in the `finally` block.

Comment: thread is lanched twice in 10 ms and the threadStated is false

Comment: Then I suspect @Xenione the thread has finished unless the `threadStarted.set(false);` is being called _before_ the end of the `run()` method.

Comment: I don't know what's going on. but I got two threads and the threadstart doesn't block the second one. I'm going to add time restriction I saw it's a good practice. thanks anyway

Comment: Can you post your code @Xenione?  Maybe to http://pastebin.com/ ?  I suspect you have a bug somewhere.

Comment: I bet `onCreate()` is being called twice @Xenione so it is creating a new `AtomicBoolean` the 2nd time.  That's not what you want.  I would move the constructor of `AtomicBoolean` up to where it is defined, out of `onCreate()`.  You could also try making it `static` if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: whith static, the threadstarted block the next one but now the map and the list view is not render

Comment: I'll let you debug that yourself @Xenione.  Best of luck.  Be sure to +1 and accept my answer if it helped.  You need to accept more answers btw.  See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work